# How long does it take until a another StackExchange profile is added to the UserFlair?

Tags: support, flair

Yesterday evening I reached more than 200 reputation on the [TeX exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) but the profile wasn't yet added to my user flair.

Isn't this update done very regularly?

Comment: Approximately every 24 hours I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait 24-48 hours for the cache to reset. the reason is that it is like the normal flair service.