# When will a new site proposal image be changed?

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal

I have created [a proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37926) for "Stack Overflow in [Azeri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azerbaijani_language)", and I have changed the proposal name to "Azeri Stack Overflow". However, [this image](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/37926.png) doesn't change. Will this change automatically?

Comment: FYI, it looks like it's now been updated :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see any change

Comment: @faridmovsumov - **Don't** add `[SOLVED]` / tag name in title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll venture the guess that this image is generated then cached (as with the Flair, for instance), and will update in time, when the cache is invalidated. If this is so, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78152/157071) describes the wait-time (for Flair):

> You have to wait 24-48 hours for the cache to reset.

There are also other references to an approximate 24hr wait-time.